# Extending PHPUnit and adding custom configuration value to PHPUnit's xml file

Tags: php, phpunit

I'm trying to extend PHPUnit behaviour, and I'd like to add a new configuration value to the phpunit.xml configuration file. So the configuration file would look something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
     colors="true"
     bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
     my_new_configuration_value="true" <!-- This is not a PHPUnit configuration value -->
>
</phpunit>
```

I've created a custom TestRunner, [using the Decorator way of extending PHPUnit](http://phpunit.de/manual/4.1/en/extending-phpunit.html), and inside the TestRunner I'd like to know the value of 'my_new_configuration_value'.
I've been reading through PHPUnit's internal code, and it seems there is no way around it, because it has hardcoded the potential configuration values in the class PHPUnit_Util_Configuration.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I added variables to the bootstrap.php file and reference them in my tests.  For instance, our legacy code had locations that wanted to exit the application under some conditions, and I can not let that happen when running tests.  Therefore, I added the following to bootstrap.php.

```
// PHP and Web server settings
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
date_default_timezone_set("America/Toronto");       // Set the default timezone
$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] = 'http://myserver';       // Set Web Server name

// Process the Include Path to allow the additional application to be set.
$IncludePaths = explode( PATH_SEPARATOR, get_include_path() );
$NewIncludePaths = array_merge( $IncludePaths, array(dirname(__FILE__) ));
set_include_path( implode( PATH_SEPARATOR, array_unique($NewIncludePaths)));    // Update Include Path

//define('PHPUNIT_RUNNING', 1); // Indicate to the code that Automated Testing is running.
```

Then in my tests, I can check the value of `PHPUNIT_RUNNING` and not do an exit on an error.

```
if(! @PHPUNIT_RUNNING )
{
    exit();
}
```

Comment: Not really what I wanted

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is following the explanation here: https://phpunit.de/manual/6.5/en/appendixes.configuration.html and add the configuration as part of one of the global arrays. What I did was to use the `$_SERVER`.

```
<php>
    <ini name="memory_limit" value="-1"/>
    <server name="foo" value="bar"/>
</php>
```

And then read the value like this

```
$_SERVER['foo']
```